# How to define a recursive sequence in Lean?

Tags: lean

Given a recursive sequence of the form
$$
f_n = \begin{cases}
c_n & n ≤ N\\
F(f_1, f_2, …, f_{n - 1}) & n > N
\end{cases}
$$
where $c_n$ are constants and $F$ is an arbitrary expression of $f_1, …, f_{n-1}$.
What is the best way to define such a sequence in Lean?

Examples:

- The Fibonacci sequence with $f_0 = 0$, $f_1 = 1$, $f_{n + 2} = f_{n + 1} + f_{n}$
- $f_0 = 1$, $f_{n + 1} = \sum_{i = 0}^n f_i$

Comment: Do you plan to compute with `f` or just do math with it?  That probably makes a difference.  [fib](https://github.com/leanprover-community/mathlib/blob/7181b3afa4631d5868cf97126d62a61e84a2bd27/src/data/nat/fib.lean) is defined with a stream in mathlib for performance.  I'm not sure if that is recommended though.

Comment: Are you trying to define a specific sequence, or the class of such sequences?

Comment: @JasonRute I intend to do math with it, think of proving properties of the fibonacci sequence using its recursion formula. Nevertheless, it would be interesting to hear about the computational aspect as well.

Comment: @AlexJBest a specific sequence

Comment: It's well known in CS that if you try to compute fib with it's usual recursive formula (which may be the best way to define it for mathematical reasoning), then you will be recomputing all the previous values exponentially many times.  It is usually used as a [first example of dynamic programming](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/program-for-nth-fibonacci-number/).

Comment: Also, will `N` be small like in your example, or large?  For example, would you be willing to handle all `N` base cases separately in each proof?

Comment: @JasonRute rather small, it would be alright to handle the base cases separately. Currently I am interested in linear recursion, where you have no choice but to handle the base cases separately most of the time.

Comment: Did you mean to include an $N$ in the application of $F$ somewhere, perhaps as $F(f_{n-N},...,f_{n-1})$? Otherwise $F$ is not a single function, but a family of functions of varying arity that happen to be equal to $c$ for small $n$.

Comment: @Eric with $F$ I did not want to have an explicit function, but any expression of some kind. So it is not necessarily required to include $N$. For instance, see the second example.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For Lean 3, I'd start out with something like:

```
def fib: ℕ → ℕ 
| 0 := 0
| 1 := 1
| (n + 2) := fib n + fib (n+1)
```

or for your second example:

```
def foo : ℕ → ℕ
| 0 := 1
| (n + 1) := (foo n) + (foo n)
```

(I modified your second example to be easier to express recursively.
You should be able to prove that `foo 0 + ... + foo n = f (n+1)`, although I admit I don't know the lean notation off hand.)

If this becomes difficult to work with for your use case, then maybe ask another question with the example you are working on as there are other ways to define this which might have better properties for your particular use case.

In particular, we are treating the sequence 0, 1, 1, 2, 3,... as a function `fib : ℕ → ℕ`.  This is a standard way to work with sequences, and is easy to prove things about.

If you also need your sequence to depend on a parameter, like maybe we are starting `fib` with two numbers `a` and `b`, then the notation is maybe a bit confusing at first:

```
def fib_general (a : ℕ) (b : ℕ) : ℕ → ℕ 
| 0 := a
| 1 := b
| (n + 2) := fib_general n + fib_general (n+1)
```

In particular notice that we don't pass `a` and `b` to the recursive call since they are in a sense fixed.

Here is a resource for more information: https://leanprover.github.io/logic_and_proof/the_natural_numbers_and_induction_in_lean.html

Answer (score 5):

Here's an implementation of a more general n-step recurrence formula, using `fin n → R` as the type of `n`-tuples:

```
import data.fin.tuple
import data.fin.vec_notation
import algebra.big_operators

/-- A general $n$-step recurrence relation, `f = recurrence F c` is the sequence
starting with $f_i = c_i$ for $i ≤ n$ and proceeding with
$f_{i+1} = F(f_{i-n},...f_i)$.

With each step, we pop the first item from `c` and append `F c`. -/
def recurrence {n : ℕ} {R : Type*} (F : (fin n.succ → R) → R) : (fin n.succ → R) → ℕ → R
| c 0 := c 0
| c (i + 1) := recurrence (fin.snoc (fin.tail c) (F c)) i
```

We can use this to build the Fibonacci numbers as:

```
def fib : ℕ → ℕ := recurrence finset.univ.sum ![0, 1]

#eval (fib ∘ (coe : fin 10 → ℕ))  -- ![0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34]
```

Note that `∘ (coe : fin 10 → ℕ)` is a convenient trick to get lean to show us the first 10 items of the sequence when using `#eval`.